# Two identical slides with pause

Tags: beamer, pause

The following code:

```latex
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1st
  \item 2nd
  \end{itemize}
  \vfill\pause
  Bottom
\end{frame}
```

produces 4 slides (instead of 3):

1. `Title` and `1st`
2. `Title`, `1st`, `2nd`
3. Identical to the previous one
4. Everything (`Title`, `1st`, `2nd`, `Bottom`)

If I remove `\vfill\pause`, I get 2 slides (instead of 3), and `bottom` appears on ***both***:

1. `Title`, `1st`, `Bottom`
2. Everything (`Title`, `1st`, `2nd`, `Bottom`)

How do I get 3 slides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Hafid Boukhoulda I suggest using `\only` but with argument `<.(1)>` which does the trick. You may think of this as "only now". I learned this trick from samcarter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1st
  \item 2nd
  \end{itemize}

 \vfill

 \only<.(1)> {Bottom}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\uncover` you can drop the alignment `[t]` that I introduced to avoid jumps.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1st
  \item 2nd
  \end{itemize}

 \vfill

 \uncover<.(1)> {Bottom}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I interpret `.(1)` ?

Comment: @sds `.(1)` means something like "only now" and `.(2)` only on the next slide and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item 1st
  \item 2nd
  \end{itemize}

 %\pause

 \vfill

 \only<3> {Bottom}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Didn't know about `\only`. However, if I add an `\item`, I would have to change `\only<3>` to `\only<4>`, so this is does not look like a nice solution.